# Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId" in Update Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a webform called `UserProfile.aspx`. After user logged-in, they can view and edit their particulars at UserProfile. I used a `SqlDataSource` and was binding the data to a `DetailsView`. In the details view, it retrieved data from 3 tables and the selecting query works fine and could display data successfully.

However, when I update the information and hit on the `Update` button in the `DetailsView` this error appears:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@UserId".

Following is the code which I get the current logged-in user(inside `UserProfile.aspx`):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ASPNETDBConnectionString1 %>" 

  SelectCommand="SELECT aspnet_Membership.Email, Details.CustName, Details.CustNum, Details.CustRole, Details.CustStatus, Details.PName, Details.PEmail, Details.PRole, Details.WedDate, aspnet_Users.UserName FROM Details INNER JOIN aspnet_Membership ON Details.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId INNER JOIN aspnet_Users ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId WHERE Details.UserId = @UserId" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 

  UpdateCommand="UPDATE Details SET CustName = @CustName, CustNum = @CustNum, CustRole = @CustRole, CustStatus = @CustStatus, PName = @PName, PEmail = @PEmail, PRole = @PRole, WedDate = @WedDate WHERE [UserId] = @UserId">

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

**EDIT**

```
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustName" type="String"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustNum" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustRole" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CustStatus" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PName" type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PEmail" type="String"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="PRole" type="String"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="WedDate" type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <br />
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        Height="29px" 
        Width="476px">

        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                SortExpression="UserName" ReadOnly="True" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                SortExpression="Email" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustName" HeaderText="CustName" 
                SortExpression="CustName" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustNum" HeaderText="CustNum" 
                SortExpression="CustNum" />    

            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustRole" HeaderText="CustRole" 
                SortExpression="CustRole" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustStatus" HeaderText="CustStatus" 
                SortExpression="CustStatus" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PName" HeaderText="PName" 
                SortExpression="PName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PEmail" HeaderText="PEmail" 
                SortExpression="PEmail" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRole" HeaderText="PRole" 
                SortExpression="PRole" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WedDate" HeaderText="WedDate" 
                SortExpression="WedDate" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

        </Fields>
        <PagerTemplate>
            <br />
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

This is the `UserProfile.aspx.cs` file:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

    // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
    // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
    //access the parameter value using e.Command.Parameters 
    //programmatically set the @UserId:

    e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();

    Response.Write(currentUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString()); 
    //When I run the webform, the UserId of the current logged-in user had displayed, 
    // the @UserId was not empty. 
}
```

I was thinking that perhaps the update query could not detect `@UserId`. But since the `@UserId` works at the `SELECT` query, why in the `UPDATE`, it wasn't???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify UserId as a parameter in the Update parameters as well as Select and Update are two independent commands. The UserId is used in the Update WHERE clause and therefore needs to be supplied.

```
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustName" type="String"  />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustNum" type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustRole" type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustStatus" type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PName" type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PEmail" type="String"  />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PRole" type="String"  />
        <asp:Parameter Name="WedDate" type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: After i add this UserId parameter, the update statement wasn't working.. data was not update when "Update" button was hit.

Comment: Are you still getting an error? Or does the page post back after the button is pressed with no change to the User's details?

Comment: Ya, it appear the same as you describe. even if I add DataKeyNames="UserName", detailsview still cannot update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare UserId in the UpdateParameters as well as the SelectParameters, as in:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="UserId" type="String" />
```

Comment: Hi, I had add in the code you gave. The error was solved, however, detailsview cannot update anymore.

Comment: Is UserId a string? If not, you need to update the type (to match, for example, int)

Comment: Have a look at [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx). You probably need to define it on your Grid.

Comment: UserId is not a string, it's a unique identifier.. I had try DataKeyNames="UserId", and an error occured : DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'UserId'.

Comment: From the looks of your code it should be UserName, not UserId, and you should define it as an int.

Comment: you mean <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" type="String" />, the userId should replave with UserName? in the detailsview, username is just for display. but UserId was my prmary key.